# I don't have access to diskstation

Tags: nas

I took out the pc (after years of use) and put in an imac.
I have a diskstation ds212j which is wired directly to the mac and it shows me an ip.
however, the imac does not see it on the network, but I do not have access through a browser either. I downloaded synology assistant but it doesn't find it either
Reading on the internet, I pinged the ip via imac terminal and I think it is responding, but the synology application still doesn't see it.
I also tried connecting it to the router but it shows the same.

If anyone had a similar problem can they help me?

[image]

Comment: Does the disk station connect to a network switch or is your goal to have a point to point network from the Mac to the disk station only so the station can not communicate to any other network?

Comment: I'm not good with networks and I'm trying to understand the terms and how they work.
Right now the Disk station (DS) is directly on the mac, previously I had the DS on the router which gave me an ip but still it didn't connect: it appeared either through a browser or through SynologyAssistant.

Comment: Did the Diskstation work correctly before, when connected to a different system?

Comment: Related https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/tutorial/What_can_I_do_to_troubleshoot_NAS_connection_problems, https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/tutorial/Unable_to_Locate_NAS

Comment: But please be aware that Synology-related problems are off-topic here.

Comment: My router shows DS's ip but I can't connect to it (I can't find it) neither via Synology Assistant nor via browser (find.synology.com or synologynas:5000, synologynas.local:5000) to access DSM - Control Panel

Comment: I understand this ;-) Is this a new NAS or have you used it before?

Comment: I have used it before. I had PC, and it worked either directly on the lan or through a router.

Comment: You may need to reset it then. If this doesn't help, please use the Synology support forum for further discussions.

Comment: I reset the device, and for the moment nothing has change. Thank you for your suggestion, I will post the problem there too.

Answer (score 2):

If the Diskstation is directly connected to the iMac via an Ethernet cable, then it will have to run a DHCP server, or the iMac will have to run one to assign IP and gateway. It must also be on a separate subnet to your WiFi otherwise it will conflict with the DHCP server on your router.

The 169.254 'address' is indicative of no IP address assigned, not an actual address, and is actually the current state of the iMac Ethernet device, not the Diskstation. So your ping is actually pinging the iMac's Ethernet, not the Diskstation.

The easiest option would be to connect the Diskstation to your router instead and let that handle address allocation. You'll then be able to see it from any device on your network, Bonjour will work properly so you can address it with a meaningful name e.g. `diskstation.local` etc...

Comment: Enabling Internet Sharing for Ethernet might also help here.

Comment: Good idea, though I've never tried that (no ethernet dongle). That would help if a connection to the router wasn't available for some reason. However, OP's extra comments appear to show that even the DS attached to the router (which gives it an IP) still doesn't appear to solve the problem. I suspect the problem might not be IP related, but maybe something else. if the Synology Assistant can't see it. I've no experience of the Synology stuff unfortunately.

Comment: So I connected the DSL to the router, it shows me ip (lan) 192.168.0.5
I try based on the guide from the company
https://kb.synology.com/en-global/DSM/tutorial/Unable_to_Locate_NAS
the assistant app doesn't see it either and I have the same problem.